# Recursively Monitor a Directory and all Sub-Directories in Python Without Watchdog

Tags: python, directory, filesystems, monitoring, watchdog

## Problem

- I want to create a program to monitor a directory and all sub-directories using python. My research has showed me multiple ways to do this using Watchdog.
- If I understand correctly, Watchdog requires that you run a script 24/7 (could be in the background) and it essentially checks the monitored directory for changes on certain intervals (please correct me if this is wrong).
- I do not want to use Watchdog if I don't have to because I would like to avoid running a python process 24/7 specifically for file monitoring.
- **I would instead like to run some sort of 'directory change detector' function manually whenever I execute the program.**

## Thoughts

- I know that to accomplish my goal of avoiding Watchdog (and background processes / daemons) I could take a snapshot of the directory by recursively walking through it with `os.walk()` (maybe there are better functions for this) and then save that output to a file (I'll call this file `last_dir_state.txt`).

  - I could also pickle this file, but I'll avoid going into that right now for this explanation...
- I could then load `last_dir_state.txt` the next time I run my program, re-run the `os.walk()` (or comparable function), and then compare the new function output to my old file.

  - I think this would work, but the problem is it will be VERY SLOW for large directories. I need a better / faster way to do this if another way exists.

    - I was thinking I could do something like recursively hashing the directory, saving the hash, and then comparing to the hash that is created when the program is next run, however this may be faster to detect that a change occurred, it wouldn't tell me **exactly what change actually occurred**.

## Visual

- As a visual this is what I want... without having to run Watchdog, and by just executing a function each time I run a program, I want the output of what changes occurred. It is OK if I have to save files locally (or create some sort of database) to do this if needed. I just need to avoid running background processes / daemons if possible.
- First function execution:

```
# Monitored Dir Structure at runtime
RootDir
|--file_1
|--SubDir_1
   |--file_2

# No Output
```

- Second function execution:

```
# Monitored Dir Structure at runtime
RootDir
|--file_1
|--SubDir_1
|  |--file_2
|  |--file_3
|
|--SubDir_2
   |--file_4

# Outputs newly added files and directories
/RootDir/SubDir_1/file_3
/RootDir/SubDir_2
/RootDir/SubDir_2/file_4
```

- Note I am not concerned as much with if say `file_1` was altered between the 2 executions (this would be nice, but I can probably figure that out if I get to that point). I am mainly just concerned with knowing what new directories and new files were created between program executions.

## Question

- In one sentence, my question is "**What is the fastest way to monitor directory changes in python without using Watchdog / background processes?**"
- Hope that all makes sense. Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: why wouldnt you just use watchdog?  and whats your question here?

Comment: @JoranBeasley as stated, I do not want to have a background process running, that is why I want to avoid Watchdog. My question is "What is the fastest way to monitor directory changes in python without using Watchdog / background processes?"

Comment: You say you're mostly just interested in files/directories created since last execution? Could you just store the last execution time and then run through all files/directories and compare the mtime of each one with that stored value?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, that is correct. I think if I could get that far, I could figure out the rest.  In order of importance I would say I need to know about 1. New directories; 2. New Files; 3. File Changes; ... I think that New Directories and New Files is basically the same problem, but then individual file changes is slightly more in-depth.